Redis: Cannot release a lock that's no longer owned
I'm trying to lock certain key.
I have httpx.Auth subclass:
from redis.asyncio import Redis
from httpx import AsyncClient, Auth
def get_redis_client():
return Redis(host=settings.redis_host, port=settings.redis_port)
class BearerAuth(Auth):
esm_url_get_token: str = urljoin(settings.esm_host, settings.esm_path_url_get_token)
token_redis_key = "esm:token"
token_expires_redis_key = "esm:token:expires"
@log_esm()
async def _get_token(self) -> Response:
    redis_client = get_redis_client()
    async with redis_client.lock(self.token_redis_key):
        if expires := await redis_client.get(self.token_expires_redis_key):
           expires = int(expires)
           if time.time() < expires:
              return await redis_client.get(self.token_redis_key)
        timeout = Timeout(settings.esm_timeout, read=None)
        client = AsyncClient(verify=settings.esm_verify, timeout=timeout)
        data = {"login": settings.esm_login, "password": settings.esm_password}
        response = await client.post(url=self.esm_url_get_token, data=data)
        token = response.json()["token"]
        await redis_client.set(self.token_redis_key, token)
        await redis_client.set(self.token_expires_redis_key, self._get_expires())
        await asyncio.sleep(settings.esm_delay_between_get_token_and_request)
        return token

def _get_expires(self):
    return int(time.time()) + 55 * 60

async def async_auth_flow(self, request: HTTPXRequest) -> typing.AsyncGenerator[HTTPXRequest, Response]:  # NOSONAR
    response = await self._get_token()
    token = response.json()["token"]
    request.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {token}"
    yield request

The main goal is to get token. If token expires refresh it. With code above I got an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py",
line 435, in run_asgi\n    result = await app(  # type:
ignore[func-returns-value]\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py",
line 78, in call\n    return await self.app(scope, receive,
send)\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/message_logger.py",
line 86, in call\n    raise exc from None\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/message_logger.py",
line 82, in call\n    await self.app(scope, inner_receive,
inner_send)\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py",
line 289, in call\n    await super().call(scope, receive,
send)\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py",
line 122, in call\n    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive,
send)\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in call\n    raise exc\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in call\n    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)\n
File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/prometheus_fastapi_instrumentator/middleware.py",
line 169, in call\n    raise exc\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/prometheus_fastapi_instrumentator/middleware.py",
line 167, in call\n    await self.app(scope, receive,
send_wrapper)\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py",
line 108, in call\n    response = await
self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/partners_logging/middlewares.py",
line 24, in logger_middleware\n    return await call_next(request)\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py",
line 84, in call_next\n    raise app_exc\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py",
line 70, in coro\n    await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect,
send_no_error)\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py",
line 79, in call\n    raise exc\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py",
line 68, in call\n    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)\n
File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py",
line 20, in call\n    raise e\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py",
line 17, in call\n    await self.app(scope, receive, send)\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py",
line 718, in call\n    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)\n
File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py",
line 276, in handle\n    await self.app(scope, receive, send)\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py",
line 66, in app\n    response = await func(request)\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py",
line 273, in app\n    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py",
line 190, in run_endpoint_function\n    return await
dependant.call(**values)\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n
File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/PycharmProjects/kz-esm/app/web/api/test.py",
line 47, in check_lock\n    await client.create_request(request,
user)\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/PycharmProjects/kz-esm/app/services/integrations/client.py",
line 151, in create_request\n    response = await
self.raw_request(action="post", url=self.esm_url_post, data=data)\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n
File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/PycharmProjects/kz-esm/app/services/integrations/client.py",
line 44, in wrapped\n    result: Response = await func(self, *args,
**kwargs)\n                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/PycharmProjects/kz-esm/app/services/integrations/client.py",
line 141, in raw_request\n    response = await getattr(client,
action)(url=url, json=data)\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py",
line 1848, in post\n    return await self.request(\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py",
line 1533, in request\n    return await self.send(request, auth=auth,
follow_redirects=follow_redirects)\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n
File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py",
line 1620, in send\n    response = await self._send_handling_auth(\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py",
line 1645, in _send_handling_auth\n    request = await
auth_flow.anext()\n              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n
File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/PycharmProjects/kz-esm/app/services/integrations/client.py",
line 110, in async_auth_flow\n    response = await self._get_token()\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/PycharmProjects/kz-esm/app/services/integrations/client.py",
line 44, in wrapped\n    result: Response = await func(self, *args,
**kwargs)\n                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/PycharmProjects/kz-esm/app/services/integrations/client.py",
line 88, in _get_token\n    async with
redis_client.lock(self.token_redis_key):\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/asyncio/lock.py", line 165, in aexit\n    await self.release()\n  File
"/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/esm-Xqw79VLb-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/asyncio/lock.py", line 262, in do_release\n    raise LockNotOwnedError("Cannot release
a lock that's no longer owned")\nredis.exceptions.LockNotOwnedError:
Cannot release a lock that's no longer owned

How to fix it?
